# How to turn a Ruby method into a block?

Tags: ruby, styles, pointfree

Is there a way to simplify the following code?

filenames is a list of filenames (strings), e.g. ["foo.txt", "bar.c", "baz.yaml"]

```
filenames.map { |f| File.size(f) }
```

Is there any way to turn "File.size" into a proc or block?  For methods on existing objects, I can do `&:method`.  Is there something analogous for module level methods?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [Object#method(method_name)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method):

```
filenames.map(&File.method(:size))
```

Comment: Yes.. this is the one I was going to give.. But you beat me.. thanks for presenting this.. *+1*.

Comment: Interesting, I would have guessed wrong about the binding order of '&'.

Answer (score 5):

```
filesize = proc { |f| File.size(f) }
filenames.map(&filesize)
```

Comment: +1 Very cool. Why haven't I thought of doing this? Now I have a great new refactoring trick.

Comment: That doesn't simplify it, it adds extra complexity.

Comment: @MartinC.Martin Indeed, it does not simplify it. But that is exactly what you asked. This answer turns the expression into a proc very simply. Blame yourself. It is your fault, not Logan's.

Comment: It doesn't simplify it in this case, but if you needed to re-use the proc it can help keep things DRY. Sometimes it also helps to give complex procs a name (through a local variable or method) to help keep your code readable when you don't care about the nitty gritty  implementation of the proc.

Comment: @MartinC.Martin fwiw, the two are subtly different in an important way. using `.method` like this returns a lambda, not just a proc. try this and you'll see what i mean: `%w{what a nice little doggo}.map(&String.new.method(:upcase))`

Answer (score 4):

Stdlib's [`Pathname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) provides a more object oriented approach to files and directories. Maybe there's a way to refactor your `filelist`, e.g. instead of:

```
filenames = Dir.entries(".")
filenames.map { |f| File.size(f) }
```

you would use:

```
require 'pathname'
filenames = Pathname.new(".").entries
filenames.map(&:size)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my actual problem, although it doesn't answer the title of the question.